# Can you set a object type to custom name instead of function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I was wondering if the following situation is possible. I am trying to write a object factory, that will construct different types of objects. What I am trying to figure out, is if it is possible in java script to set the type as something other then a function or object? Similar to in C# how a class instance of Car is a typeof Car, even though the base type is object. Hopefully I am explaining this clearly. The best way to explain it, is demonstrated below:

```
var object = function(){

switch(id){
    case 1:
        $_objInstance = new Car();
    break;
  case 2: 
    $_objInstance = new Animal();
    break;

 return $_objInstance;
}


function Car(){
    this.Name = "GM";
}


document.write(object instanceof Car);
or
typof(

object) == Car //is this possible?
```

Thanks in advance! Happy coding:)

Comment: you can't introduce new reflections to `typeof`, but you can specify a constructor for `instanceof`targeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to figure out, is if it is possible in java script to set the type as something other then a function or object?

No, you can't. However:

- JavaScript does have an `instanceof` operator you can use to test an instance to see if it's likely to have been constructed by a given constructor:

  ```
    if (obj instanceof Car) {
        // ...
    }
  ```
- `Function#name` remains unreliable in the wild (in that JavaScript engines don't set it reliably yet), you but you set it explicitly on your constructor functions:

  ```
    Car.name = "Car";
  ```

...and then use `obj.constructor.name` to find the name of the constructor. That relies on the object inheriting the `constructor` property correctly, which it will if you don't mess up the default object on the function's `prototype` property.

Several years back I [wrote a blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html) about `typeof`, `instanceof`, `Object.prototype.toString`, and various other ways you can use to determine what something is, although I left off that option of just setting your own name.

Here's an example of using `.constructor.name`:

```js
function Car() {
}
Car.name = "Car";

function Animal() {
}
Animal.name = "Animal";

console.log("Randomly constructing 10 Cars or Animals:");
for (var n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    var x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? new Car() : new Animal();
    console.log("We got: " + x.constructor.name);
}
```

---

When I said above

> That relies on the object inheriting the `constructor` property correctly, which it will if you don't mess up the default object on the function's `prototype` property.

let me give you an example that messes it up, so you know what to keep an eye out for. You routinely see people doing this:

```
// PROBLEMATIC: Wipes out the `constructor` property
function Car() {
}
Car.prototype = {
    drive: function() {
    }
    // ...
};
```

That is, rather than *augmenting* the object that `Car.prototype` got originally, they *replace* it. I prefer to *augment* (e.g., don't replace the whole object, just add properties to it), for various reasons, but if you *do* replace it you can just make sure you give the new one the correct `constructor`:

```
// Keeps `constructor` correct
function Car() {
}
Car.prototype = {
    constructor: Car,
    drive: function() {
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks, an apologies for the delayed response. I was thinking about using the instance of. I do like what you explained above though about the "constructor.name".  Now, I love and am a huge fan of Javascript. My main work is with this and also c#. I have to admit though, I worked a lot in jQuery, and never used the prototype. Should I get more into this if I plan on writing more extensive and heavier Javascript code? Meaning real projects, not just using it for regular web applications.

Comment: Thanks also for the example explaining what to watch for.

Comment: @Casey: The useful thing about prototypes is that they let you share functionality across all instances created with the constructor function. They also let you *add* functionality (by adding to the prototype), which shows up on all instances (even ones already created) because of the way prototypical inheritance works (instances have a live link back to the prototype object). Whether you need that will depend on the kinds of projects you're doing.